# How to rewrite an algorithm into python

Tags: python, algorithm, jupyter-notebook, primes, prime-factoring

I am new to Python and want to create an algorithm that would give an output of a list of prime factors of an input, for example:

```
Input:   factorise(684)
```

```
Output:   2 x 2 x 3 x 3 x 19
```

Or something along those lines

I would need to define a prime number to begin with so the algorithm knows when it has found a prime factor, so was following a function along these lines:

```
num = 13
if num > 1:
   for i in range(2, num//2):
      if (num % i) == 0:
      print(num, "is not a prime number")
      break
      else:
         print(num, "is a prime number")
            else:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

I have based this code on another question, applying it to my code the first issue I have come across is indentation (I'm thinking this is a quick fix) as python reports an error but changing one level has a knock on effect and it's proving tedious to align everything where necessary

Secondly this code is written to produce a written output as opposed to a definition - I was hoping someone could help me adapt the lines beginning 'print' as I was unsure what command to use.

Finally I need to work on bringing this together to create a final algorithm - if there any ideas on how to do this that would be appreciated but if I can form this definition I should have a decent starting point to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your checking if a number is prime

```
num = 13
isPrime = True
for i in range(2, num//2):
    if (num % i) == 0:
        isPrime = False
        break
if isPrime:
    print(num, "is a prime number")
else:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

Comment: As an optimisation, you can check up to `int(sqrt(num))` (inclusive), as any number above it will require another divisor that is below it.

Comment: True. Actually if the OP needs to check for several numbers to be primes, it's better to construct a list of prime numbers using the Sieve or Eratosthenes

Answer (score 1):

If you need a lot of divisions to determine if a number is a prime, you maybe try an other approach where your algorithm has no idea what a prime is. Simply start with divisor 2 try to divide your number by this. as soon as the number cannot be divided by the divisor any more, increment the divisor and so on until divisor == number.

This way you get a prime factorisation without ever checking a numbe to be prime.

**Example:**

| divisor | remaining number | prime factors so far |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 684 |  |
| 2 | 342 | 2 |
| 2 | 171 | 2 * 2 |
| 3 | 57 | 2 * 2 * 3 |
| 3 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 4 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 5 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 6 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 7 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 8 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 9 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 10 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 11 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 12 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 13 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 14 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 15 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 16 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 17 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 18 | 19 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 |
| 19 | 1 | 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 19 |

Output:   2 x 2 x 3 x 3 x 19

P.s. of cause you could stop increasing divisor when it reaches `sqrt(remaining_number)` but calculating this is quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more efficient way of checking if a number is prime.

```
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1):
        if(num%i == 0):
            return False
    return True
```